# Download problem

Tags: downloads, disk

I'm trying to create a disk and I've downloaded the installation file twice and my computer can't find it. If I open the Firefox downloads box it shows up there, but when I click it nothing comes up and when I right-click it Open and Open Containing Folder are both in grey.
On the downloads folder Owner Downloads, it isn't there at all.

What what did I do wrong? Can some kind person talk my computer-illiterate self through this?

Answer (score 0):

The default downloads go to ~/Downloads.  If you still can't find it open a terminal windows and type

```
find | grep ubuntu-12.10
```

and that should find it for you if it's in your home directory anywhere.  To search the entire hard drive:

```
cd /
find | grep ubuntu-12.10
```

You could also use the Unity dash to search for you.

Edit:

I don't know where Windows put your download, but I always used to specifically tell it where to put the download.  Go to [this page](http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/CDs-Ubuntu/12.10/) (official US mirror) and right click on the file that you want (suggest ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso) and select "save link as".  It will prompt you where to save the .iso file.  Also download the MD5SUMS file and [check the md5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of the file that you just downloaded.  This can save you hours of work and heartache in case there was a subtle problem with the download.

Comment: Thanks fabricator4. I took your advice and I got "result not found"
I wish I knew how to take a screen shot. This is just so weird.

Comment: You didn't say you were on Windows...  I take it that "result not found" is the Windows search.  I'm amending my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have it downloading and will try it that way. Thank you both for all your time!

Answer (score 0):

When the Firefox window pops up asking what to do, you have to choose «Save» (not «Open») and the file goes —per default— to the «Downloads» folder.

Comment: That's what I did, I'm not sure what happened.

Comment: @Lauren. Open Firefox > Edit > Preferences. In «General» tab, check the «Save files to» option. This is the folder your download has to be. Otherwise, change this option to «Always ask me where to save files»

Comment: It is in that folder in Firefox. But i can't open it from that folder. When I right click it there I get a dialog box with 
Open,
Open containing folder,Go to Dowlnoad Page, Copy Download Link, Select all and Remove From List. I can't click on either Open or Open containing folder, the text is in grey and nothing happens

Comment: @Lauren. So, if you open a file manager (Nautilus, for instance) you can find your .iso file (the one you've downloaded) in your Downloads folder?

Comment: I don't have Nautilus. When I open the download folder from the Firefox options, it shows the download there, but I can't open the file. When I open the downloads folder from my start menu (windows vista) or do a search for the file it isn't there.

Comment: @Lauren. I think you cannot «open» a disk image. Instead, you have to «burn it» on a CD or DVD with a proper program. Check for instance this [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Burn-a-CD-or-DVD-from-an-ISO-file)

Comment: I can't find the disk image file to burn. When I go to windows Explorer it isn't there.

Comment: @Lauren. If you click the «Start» button (windows key), you can type the name of your download: «ubuntu» and see the result. Check also this [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Find-a-file-or-folder).

Comment: I've done that and it's not there. How I've done this before is I've downloaded the file, inserted and formatted the disk, then, from the firefox downloads file, I hit "Open containing folder" and then when that box comes up, I burn to disk. ~ This time, "open containing folder does not work and I can't seem to get it to download so that I can burn it. I'm pretty discouraged as this seems like a rather idiot-proof process but it's just not working. I don't know why Firefox says it's downloaded (twice!!) and windows says it does not exist.